# mPDF não alinha colspan com Text-align

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

Boa tarde galera.

Pessoal, eu tenho um layout de tabelas que na tela e impressão está exibindo como esperado, com os textos alinhados à esquerda e demais formatações.

Porém quando envio pro mPDF no PHP pra ele processar, ele traz tudo como se fosse `text-align:center;` Mesmo eu tentando colocar na mão um `* { text-align: left }` ele não interpreta.

Ai descobri que o problema está em um `colspan="14"` que tenho, que serve como uma linha, e o mPDF parece não conseguir alinhar no colspan.

A linha que isso acontece é como este exemplo

```
<tr class="tit">
     <th colspan="14">Vendedor: Fulano da Silva</th>
</tr>
```

Alguém tem uma ideia de como formatar esse estilo?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver usando start ao invés de left, no css adicionei então:

```
.tit {
  text-align: start;
}
```